# Adding multiple parameters to JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have the following code below, that iterates through months to create API links, it is then exported to a JSON file:

```
import calendar
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

token = 
clientId = 
siteId = '276'     #416, 414, 207, 233, 237, 251, 262, 276
filename = f'{clientId}-{siteId}.json'

def get_datas(year):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        r = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
        start = f"{year}-{month:0>2d}-01"
        end = f"{year}-{month:0>2d}-{r[1]}"
        
        url = f"apilink/getKwh?token={token}&clientId={clientId}&siteId={siteId}&from={start}&to={end}"
       
        response = urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        yield data

datas = []
for year in (2019, 2020, 2021):
    datas.extend(get_datas(year))
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    json.dump(datas, f, indent=4)
```

Currently I am setting **siteId** = to one value, is there away I can have it go through a list of siteID's instead and it to the JSON

Comment: Yes, store the siteId values in a list and iterate over it. I'm not sure what difficulty you were facing, since you seem to know how to write a loop.

Comment: And add `token`, `siteID`, and `clientID` as parameters to `get_datas`.

Comment: I never wrote this, could you perhaps show me a snippet